# Unity UI Elements give different errors with different resolution

Tags: unity-game-engine, canvas, scale

I'm trying to make simple "Plants vs Zombies" game. I have set background and squares to specify where should AI spawn or where  player place their  items(such as plants). But I have really big problem with resolution and scale. I have been trying to understand and solve this issue for days.   I can't fit all of elements properly to game scene . Every  solution I tried  created another problem

Those are images of problems that I got  for solutions that I tried

[It's my standart cansvas settings(1920*1080 resolution)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qCnD.png)

[Those are squares with 16:9 resolution.It looks normal(I stretched all squares on canvas)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqZiq.png)

[But If I  change resolutin to 4:3 I get that problem(squares still be stretched)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yp9r.png)

[If I don't stretch squares on canvas, I meet with that problem(The squares are either out of bond or much inside for some resolutions)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUwlI.png)

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:
-Change to "Screen Match Mode: Match Widht or Height" on Canvas.
-"Reference Pixels Per Unit : 100" on Canvas.
-And set images anchors center.